# Java: How can i get the instances number of specific a class from jmx

Tags: java, class, monitoring, jmx

all

It's about to supervise the instances numbers of a specific class inside the JVM Memory.

Why ?
Because I would like to monitor the instances number of several java classes in my tomcat 7 server.
I would like to do this because it take too much time to make "heap dumps" with jmap and parse the heap with JvisualVM.

Here may jmap command:
/..../jdk1.7.0_79/bin/jmap  -dump:format=b,file=filename.hprof [PID]

Restriction:
I would prefer to not modify my code for those "monitored" classes.
I could add Mbean to my server to manage this.

Actually I don't know how to retrieve all classes instances from HeapMemory.
Maybe I am in the wrong way to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use static variable for counting and create MBean with method that returns this variable.

Comment: Yes I had thought about this but in my case it's not easy to do.